# php select datetime range

Tags: php, mysql, date-range

I want to use php to select records from Mysql in date range.
for example, i want to select date range ( 2011-02-23, 2011-02-24)

```
$query = "select * from table where date_field between '2011-02-23' and '2011-02-24'";
mysql_query($query);
```

It does not work.
So, what is the correct format I should use?

Comment: Could you give an error message? That query should be fine, so there could be any number of things wrong between php and the database.

Comment: I checked the type of variable returned. $result = mysql_query($query). It is boolean. actually, it should be resource.

Comment: What format is the date_field field in your database? DATETIME, DATE, TIMESTAMP or TIME? Or even a string or an int. I often store my dates in int format because its easy to do comparisons on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query="select * from table where date_field >'2011-02-23' "
  ." and date_field<date_add('2011-02-24', interval 1 day)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="select * from table where date_field > '2011-02-23' and date_field < '2011-02-24'";
```

Comment: I tried this. it does not work either. The returned variable type is still boolean. $result = mysql_query($query). It should be resource.

Comment: Hmm allright. I would suggest to use try/catch or mysql_errno & mysql_error in the future to get the Error # and the Error message